# How do I say what something is made out of?

Tags: grammar, translation, words, usage

The exact thing I want to know how to say is 'The wristwatch is made out of gold' and 'The wristwatch is gold and black in colour'. Would saying this be the same as talking about a house being made of wood (for example)?

Comment: I will let Paul Gilbert answer your question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHg03scDqTU

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say 「～～でできている」, as in:

> この腕時計は、[金]{きん}で**できている**。 *The wristwatch is made out of gold.*
>   この家は、木で**できている**。 *This house is made of wood.*
>   女の子は何で**できている**の？ *♪What are little girls made of?*

Comment: I hope you are not considering too much on what we (non-natives) would/should say, instead of letting us know the natural choice of a native. Even if you would use the above structure of a wristwatch (where it being gold is something worth mentioning separately), would you really use the same expression for a 木造一戸建て?　Maybe, if assuming the person has never been outside Manhattan or 中央区) but assuming that a wooden house is not that exotic?

Comment: Further to Chocolate's answer, it may be helpful to add/clarify the cases of 「〜は〜で作られている」("made of") and 「〜は〜から作られている」("made from"). 

I see「〜は〜で作られている」as essentially equivalent with 「〜は〜でできている」; i.e. used in cases where the original material is essentially in its original form. e.g. このテーブルは木でできている。or このテーブルは木で作られている。are both grammatical, because the wood used for the table is still obviously wood.

But, if the material has gone through some change, and isn't in its original form 「〜は〜から作られている」is - strictly speaking - correct.  Good examples might be: ワインはブドウから作られている。or パンは小麦から作られている。

Answer (score 1):

While in English the word "gold" can easily mean both the colour and the metal, the Japanese word for "golden colour" is "金色" and the word for gold (metal) is "金" (read as きん), which makes it less ambiguous.

Although there is also word "黄金" which indeed can mean both the colour and the metal, and "金" read as "かね", which can mean "money" or "metal" in general (any metal, not specifically gold).

"made of ~" could be translated as ~で作った or ~から作った (or できた).

So I would translate those as:

The wristwatch is made out of gold: (この)腕時計は金から作った。

The wristwatch is gold and black in colour: (この)腕時計は金色と黒だ。

黒と金色の腕時計 - "black and golden coloured watch"

金の腕時計 - "gold watch"